# Is there any way to set the overall bitrate of a video file in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

From what I understand, the overall bitrate of a file is a sum of the bitrate of all streams(video and audio) and the container bitrate. Ffmpeg provides option to set video bitrate and audio bitrate individually using -b:v and -b:a flags.

Can we set a bitrate for the whole file using ffmpeg and let it calculate the individual stream bitrates on its own?

Comment: There is no option in ffmpeg to do this.

Comment: @llogan what is the best way to achieve this? I am looking to restrict the overall bitrate so that it is easier for streaming but have no clue how to set/restrict container bitrate.

Comment: Use `-b:v` or `-b:a` per stream and leave some room for muxing overhead (maybe 1% or so, but it is a blind, uneducated guess because you didn't provide any details about your formats).